# Selecting jQuery First Child without a specific class

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, jquery-1.4

I have a page with nested divs being used as Js/Jq tabs. When you click on a parent tab, it fires the click event of the first child underneath the parent.

```
$('#topRow .pricing').click(function () {
    $('#secondRow .pricing').css('display', 'block');
    $('#secondRow .pricing div.tab:first-child').trigger('click');
});
```

This functionality works great as is. However, we're adding functionality to effectively "lock" tabs by adding a "locked" class dynamically via c#/linq and then on window.ready we unbind all the tabs with the "locked" class and color them grey to indicate that they are disabled.

I'm trying to modify the last line of the jQuery code above to click the first child that DOESN'T have the "locked" class.

```
    $('#secondRow .pricing div.tab:first-child').trigger('click');
```

Translating that into plainspeak, it's saying "In the Second Row, fire the click event of the first child tab in the 'pricing' group". I'd like it to say "In the Second Row, fire the click event of the first child tab in the 'pricing' group that DOES NOT have the class 'locked'".

I've tried using:

```
    $('#secondRow .pricing div.tab:not(.locked):first-child').trigger('click');
```

Which seems the correct way to do this, but it still looks at the first child and just doesn't fire the trigger('click'). Am I missing something?

Here is the html:

```
<div id="topRow">               
    <div class="pricing tab" runat="server" id="pricingTop">
        <div class="tabLeft">
            <div class="tabMain">
                Pricing
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="secondRow">    
    <div id="pricingTabGroup" runat="server" class="pricing tabGroup" style="display:none">
        <div id="pricingProductA" runat="server" class="tab locked pricingProductA">
            <div class="tabLeft">
                <div class="tabMain">
                    ProductA
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="pricingProductB" runat="server" class="tab pricingProductB">
            <div class="tabLeft">
                <div class="tabMain">
                    ProductB
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The "locked" class is added through C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool ProductA = //some linq query

    if (!ProductA)
    {
        LockTab(pricingProductA);
    }

    protected void LockTab(HtmlGenericControl tab)
    {
        //Adds the "locked" class
        tab.Attributes.Add("class", "locked");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your HTML, because the query seems fine

Comment: a wild guess but try  $('#secondRow .pricing:not(div.tab.locked) div.tab:first-child')

Comment: Thad Blankenship below has solved the problem! Thank you so much for offering help as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('#secondRow .pricing div.tab').not('.locked').children().first().trigger('click');
```

Your selector looks fine though. Usually a good idea to minimize your selector complexity.

Also remember that every time you do a selector jQuery traverses the dom, so its best to save returned elements for a given selector as a variable(for performance) eg:

```
var $tab_containers = $('#secondRow .pricing div.tab');
```

And then use it multiple times like

```
$tab_containers.not('.locked').children().first().trigger('click');
```

Comment: Let me give this a try.

Comment: @RockiesMagicNumber Note that I just edited this post to reflect the DOM structure you added to your post.

Comment: let me refresh, but it's working. Stay with me a moment longer.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm very poor at jQuery thus far (I work best between TSQL and C# and up until recently, jQ/js functionalities have been sort of "nice to have"), so if you don't mind, what did I do wrong here? Also, thank you for posting the "var selector" storage lines there. I can queue this js page up for a refactor now.

Comment: @RockiesMagicNumber Honestly, I'm not sure. It looks like your selector should work the same as mine. I'm assuming its some issue with having multiple custom selectors (the ones prefixed with a colon).

Comment: Well, thank you again very much. This has been a great help to me.